# centerOnScroll in Fancybox 2.0?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've been using Fancybox < 2.0 until now, and I set centerOnScroll to false on mobile devices because otherwise it's impossible to fill out a form on a fancybox overlay, it just moves around like crazy once you focus on the text fields.

I just updated to Fancybox 2.0 http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ and I don't see this option in the documentation. Is it gone? Because it's totally necessary, I think. Any idea, if it's gone, of what could I change in the code to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fancybox v2.x the API option is "`fixed`" so

what it was in v1.3.x

```
'centerOnScroll': false
```

in v2.x is now

```
fixed: false
```

Options in v1.3.x are not compatible with v2.x options, so you need to upgrade all your API options when migrating from v1.3.x (or better start from scratch)

Comment: Seems like 'fixed' doesn't center on scroll, yes. But I have the same problem. I have a dialog with some text fields and in smartphones, if I focus on one of them and start writing, the whole dialog moves a lot, disappears from the screen (it's very zoomed-in, smartphone focus style). Any ideas can I change to make this disappear? Before 2.x, centerOnScroll: false fixed this, but fixed: false doesn't, now.

Comment: The fixed v2.x option replaces centerOnScroll v1.3.x indeed. I guess you would need to open an issue at github (https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues) so the developer can analyze it (and eventually fix it). Please provide him with most extended information and code possible.